# Jupiter Notebook not connecting to Kernel

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, websocket, localhost, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Jupyter notebook for some studying. I just updated all my python libraries and now when I start a new python notebook, it just continuously says connecting to kernel in yellow.

Do I have to change something using my terminal to tell my mac to use the localhost? I have been trying to initiate an EC2 instance for another project, which I put on hold until I can figure out why that is not working, but now I can't connect locally anymore.

Sorry, I am so vague in my explanation but it is literally my first time trying to remote connect and now I think I might have messed up the paths or something.

I am reading something about websockets on git?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda. This seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by downgrade tornado to 5.1.1 version.
Apparently, the 6.0 version has some issues.

Reference
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4399